# How to use gstreamer to save webcam video to file?

Tags: c, opencv, gstreamer, avi, x264

[I've been trying to get emgu to save same webcam video to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034131/x264-error-message-when-capturing-video)

The problem is opencv only ssupports avi, and avi does not seem to suit a format like X264 very well.

Could I use Gstreamer to do this for me in C?

It would be good if I could choose the file format and container type too. It would be good if I could use a format like schrodinger dirac.

I'm new to GStreamer so I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right track here.

**EDIT**

I've managed to capture the webcam video using

> gst-launch-0.10 ksvideosrc ! autovideosink

Now how to transcode this to a format like H264 or dirac ...?

**EDIT**

> gst-launch-0.10  ksvideosrc num-buffers=10 ! decodebin2 !
>   ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink
>   location=video.mkv

This seems to create a file, but VLC player can't read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> gst-launch-0.10
>
> ```
> ksvideosrc !  
> decodebin2 !      
> ffmpegcolorspace !
> schronc ! 
> matroskamux ! 
> filesink location=gopro2.mkv
> ```

Seems to handle dirac encoding

And this

> gst-launch-0.10 ksvideosrc num-buffers=500 ! decodebin2 !
>   ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=gopro2.mp4

Handles x264

Answer (score 8):

This pipeline captures video from webcam, encodes it in h264 and finally uses flv container to store it at any specified location.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux ! filesink location=xyz.flv
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `-e` should be added to the end if you use `ctrl+c` to end capturing. Also, could you please explain how one could change the frame rate and resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This directly captures the video from webcam and writes as an avi file which will be played-back by  VLC player.

```
   gst-launch v4l2src ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=output.avi
```

Hope this help!