# Qt: How to create a .mp4 from a collection of QOpenGLFramebufferObjects or QImages or Glunit textures

Tags: c++, ios, qt, ffmpeg, qtmultimedia

I am developing a Qt app for iOS, Android & OSX.

**Situation:**
I have an `std::vector` of [QOpenGLFramebufferObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html)s. Each `QOpenGLFramebufferObject` can of course provide its own [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qimage.html) or a `GLunit` texture by doing a [takeTexture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglframebufferobject.html#takeTexture). So you can also say that I have a collection of `QImage`s or `GLunit` textures.

**Problem:**
Now, I want to create a `.mp4` video file out of these which works at least on iOS, Android & OSX.

How should I do this? Any examples doing this with Qt? Which classes in Qt should I be looking into?

**ffmpeg** or **GStreamer**, whichever works with Qt. But I need to know how to pass these *QImages or Glunit textures* into the required component or API to create the video.

Should I use [QVideoEncoderSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoencodersettings.html) to create the video?

Comment: I doubt Qt is ready to accomplish this but I myself operate with QStreamer programmatically (what can GStreamer do for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152303/how-to-use-gstreamer-to-save-webcam-video-to-file). Look at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/ QtGStreamer or write own framework (which I did).

Comment: Strange. Qt has this whole [Multimedia](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-index.html) module. But nothing to support creation of a video from simple QImages. I am ok to use GStreamer if required. How can I try this [QtGStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/). Does it work on android & iOS?

Comment: The problem with Multimedia module is that it may or may not work and we will never know why. I cannot use it, especially in embedded project.