# X264 recording video Emgucv C#

Tags: c#, video, emgucv, video-recording

I'm writing a program to save some webcam video to a file. I'm using the x264 codec found here x264.

When I try writing frames to a file I get this warning message poping up. It still records the video. But I don't want this popup showing on the screen.

x264vfw [warning]: Few frames probably would be lost. Ways to fix this:

x264vfw [warning]: -if you use VirtualDub or its fork than you can enable 'VirtualDub Hack' option

x264vfw [warning]: -you can enable 'File' output mode

x264vfw [warning]: -you can enable 'Zero Latency' option

**Is there anyway to config "File ouput mode" or "Zero Latency" by using C# or C++ or command line?**

This is the code:

```
public static void StartCapture()
{
    try
    {
        capture = new Capture();
        capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);  //1920
        capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080); //1080

        CaptureOutput = new VideoWriter
        (
            "capture output.avi",
            CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'),
            50, //fps
            (int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), 
            (int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT), 
            true
        );

        if (capture != null)
        {
            capture.ImageGrabbed += SaveFrame;
            capture.Start();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}

static void SaveFrame(System.Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> video;
    video = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
    CaptureOutput.WriteFrame(video);
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034131/x264-error-message-when-capturing-video